# Медленное выполнение программы

Tags: c#

Написал программу которая считывает информацию из файла в лист и выводит N раз. 
Но программа работает оооочень медленно. 1000000 записей за 9 минут, а надо за 1-2 .-. Подскажите в чём может быть причина? Как сделать выполнение быстрее. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace FirstTask
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> MyInformation = new List<string>();
        static Random rand = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int countOfValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string region = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> countOfSomeElenents = new List<int>();
            List<string> namesOfFile = new List<string>() { "cities", "streets", "house", "name", "surname", "numbers"};
            foreach (string i in namesOfFile)
            {
                countOfSomeElenents.Add(CreateFileStream(region, i));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < countOfValue; i++)
            {
                OutPutInformation(countOfSomeElenents);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        static int CreateFileStream (string region, string nameOfFile){
            FileStream file1 = new FileStream(String.Format("..\\..\\Data\\{0}_{1}.txt", region,nameOfFile), FileMode.Open); //создаем файловый поток
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file1,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            while (String.Compare(reader.ReadLine(), null) > 0)
            {
                InformationToArray(Convert.ToString(reader.ReadLine()));
            }
            MyInformation.Remove(null);
            return MyInformation.Count;
        }

        static void InformationToArray (string someInformations){
            MyInformation.Add(someInformations);
        }

        static void OutPutInformation(List<int> countOfSomeElenents)
        {
            int min = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < countOfSomeElenents.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(MyInformation[rand.Next(min,countOfSomeElenents[i])]);
                min = countOfSomeElenents[i];
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно как-то сузить задачу? Код читает данные, обрабатывает их, выводит на экран. Какая часть занимает много времени? Можно ли ее изолировать и сократить код в вопросе?

Comment: @defaultlocale сам вывод из листа в консоль

Comment: Во-первых, может тогда убрать из примера все лишнее, оставить только цикл с миллионом `Console.WriteLine`? Во-вторых, обязательно выводить в консоль? Проблема с консолью в том, что много времени уходит на отрисовку "потока" при выводе. В файл выводить будет быстрее.

Comment: к сожалению, обязательно. А может вывод из массива будет быстрее происходить, нежеле из List. Или это не играет роли?

Comment: Не думаю что это поможет, скорее всего тут тормозит сама консоль.

Comment: Вывод на консоль огромных объемов текста - это всегда медленно. Перебрать 1000000 - это миллисекунды, что для массива, что для листа. У вас тормозит вывод на консоль. Если вам эти 1M записей не нужны именно на консоли - выводите в файл.

Comment: А зачем вам нужно это `Convert.ToString(reader.ReadLine())`, если у вас уже `StreamReader reader`, т.е. уже поток читается как текст?

Comment: @Bulson изначально считывал другое значение, спасибо

Comment: Закомментируйте цикл вывода результатов в консоль и посмотрите сколько времени потребуется программе на сей раз.

Comment: Можно вывести только последние N-значений, где N - число строк в буфере консоли. Буфер консоли сильно меньше чем вам нужно, всего 300 строк по умолчанию, и весь предыдущий вывод в любом случае будет потерян. Скорость резко увеличится.

Comment: @Павел Кушнеревич любой IO можно ускорить если повысить гранулярность отсылки, то есть посылать на консоль не по одному числу, а сразу несколько

Comment: Мне кажется, или строки будут обрабатываться через одну? В цикле, в условии проверки вы читаете одну строку, сравниваете ее с NULL-ом, а в теле цикла читаете следующую строку, и ее уже обрабатываете.